# Traveling Outside USA as a visitor

Tags: usa, international-travel, mexico, connecting-flights

I'm from Mexico and planning a trip to Japan, and so me is a few thousand dollars cheaper and way faster to do it from LAX, than from my own country.
I do have an American Visa B-2 type (Tourist). 
**What problems could there be regarding my situation**? 
and
***Are there any extra steps in me taking an international flight within the US as a foreigner?***
Thank you so much in advance, I really don't want to have an issue and have never done a flight like so.

Answer (score 5):

> What problems could there be regarding my situation?

You could be denied entry into the US. Since you already have a B visa, this is probably rather unlikely.

> Are there any extra steps in me taking an international flight within the US as a foreigner?

Not really.  The airline will report your departure to the US government, so you might have to show your US visa when you leave for Japan, but otherwise the process will be essentially the same as it is for a US citizen.

Comment: The airline is unlikely to check the OP's USA visa upon departure from the USA. The USA visa is just permission to apply for admission. It holds no value once a passenger has already been admitted. They will be more interested in the required visa (if any) for Japan.

Comment: @greatone I know that.  But when I flew on Delta from JFK to Dakar a couple of years ago, the airline required my wife to scan her US visa at the checkin kiosk.  I don't know what specific condition triggered this requirement, but it succeeded in convincing me to use my US passport instead of my other one.  We normally leave the US on European carriers, where there has been no such requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You want to transit through the USA using a B2 visa. You are unlikely to have any problems.

> If you already have a valid visitor (B) visa, you may be able to use it to transit the United States. If you are a citizen of a participating country, you may be able to transit the United States on the Visa Waiver Program.

https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/other-visa-categories/transit.html